# Zapier to look up Twitter URL mentions

Tags: twitter, zapier

**Is it possible to create a Zap that will look-up URL mentions on Twitter?**

Been scratching my head with this one, since simply entering URL into Zapier's Twitter Search field doesn't seem to do the trick.

Is it at all possible? Twitter uses its URL shortening service t.co on all links posted. Might this be a reason for me not being able to find any mentions of my URL even when I post one myself? Twitter's native search function finds URL just fine, but not Zapier.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured it out.

**First, use Twitter's special "url" prefix for URL search:**

> url:amazon - will find URL with the word “amazon” anywhere within it.

Second, most importantly, it looks like the Twitter account I used for testing got ignored after a couple of same URL posts. So be aware of that too.